# Using an HID bar code scanner in visual basic .net

Tags: vb.net, controls, hid

I am using visual basic 2019 and I need to use a bar code scanner as an HID device, not as a keyboard wedge. Is there a form control like the RS-232 serial port control that I can add to a form and place code in event handling routines to handle received data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this particular area, but I did find a few classes that could be helpful to you:

[`Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.HidDevice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.hiddevice)

and

[`System.IO.Ports.SerialPort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.8)

There are instructions and examples on the msdn pages. You should be able to create an instance of one of these classes and use it to communicate with your hardware.

Comment: When I attempt to add a reference for 'Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.dll' I get: A reference to c:\...Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component. I think I may not have a good file as I can't regsvr32 it and the sfc utility doesn't seem to like it. I'm searching microsoft's website to download a trusted version of this file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `SerialPort` control you can find in the toolbox. You will also need to include `Imports System.IO.Ports` in your form.

Then it's just a matter of configuring the port with calls such as:

```vb
    SerialPortScanner.BaudRate = "19200"
    SerialPortScanner.ReadTimeout = 5000
    SerialPortScanner.DataBits = 8
    SerialPortScanner.Parity = Parity.None
    SerialPortScanner.Open()
    SerialPortScanner.DiscardOutBuffer()    'start fresh
    SerialPortScanner.DiscardInBuffer()
```

Finally you read bytes with something like:

```vb
    CharBuff = SerialPortHCT.ReadByte()
```

Of course, you will need to loop on reading bytes and know when to stop (assuming you have to read them as bytes and don't have the luxury of having a scanner that sends delimited strings.

The tricky part is if you have to controller the scanner with non-printable characters. I have done this by making some constants like this:

```vb
    Const ACK As Byte = 6   ' ACKnowledge ASCII Code
```

Then you can write out the byte like this:

```vb
    SerialPortScanner.Write({ACK}, 0, 1) ' Send ACK byte
```

There are other settings and controls, but that's the basics.